# How can I fix 'ImportError: DLL load failed while importing trace' in cartopy on Python?

Tags: python, importerror, cartopy

I am beginner in this.I am stuck at this point. Getting error this error again and again. I install all require whl files.
version of cartopy 0.20.2, pyproj 3.1.0 ,shapely 1.8.0

Can somebody help  ?? Please

```
import cartopy.crs as crss
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[21], line 1
----> 1 import cartopy.crs as crss

File c:\users\dheeraj chouhan\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\cartopy\__init__.py:110
    105     pass
    108 # Commonly used sub-modules. Imported here to provide end-user
    109 # convenience.
--> 110 import cartopy.crs
    111 import cartopy.feature  # noqa: F401  (flake8 = unused import)

File c:\users\dheeraj chouhan\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\cartopy\crs.py:27
     24 from pyproj.exceptions import ProjError
     25 from shapely.prepared import prep
---> 27 import cartopy.trace
     30 try:
     31     # https://github.com/pyproj4/pyproj/pull/912
     32     from pyproj.crs import CustomConstructorCRS as _CRS

ImportError: DLL load failed while importing trace: The specified module could not be found.
```

I tried to install whl files of shapely and pyproj from same site but that didn't worked in my case.I didn't find and other way.